# which suspension seatpost for a granny who wants a comfortable ride while cruising the neighborhood

Tags: suspension, seatpost

It is so hard to find info for the granny who just wants some general info for a comfortable ride.  I don't need a professional mountainbike seatpost and not worried about if it is carbon or not, don't understand the difference between long or short travel, not concerned about weight of the seatpost or competion.

But I am a tall granny with a hard tail commuter/crusier ebike and the bumps hurt my back.  I don't want to spend several hundred dollars if 50.00 will do.

Does anyone have suggestions.  I weigh about 155 and tall.
Nancy

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid questions seeking product advice are off topic here:

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

*Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they tend to become obsolete quickly. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.*

However, my advice would be to investigate the possibility of running larger, higher quality tyres at a lower pressure before experimenting with suspension seatposts.

Larger tyres, with more supple casings, run at lower pressure conform to the surface much better and greatly reduce the impact of road imperfections.